# Azure Storage - Is it possible to create two or more static website containers in one storage account?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I'm wondering if is supported or possible to manage several static file web servers in the same storage account.

Looking around in the options for Static Website in an Azure Storage account, it only has a toogle an only one primary endpoint and an associated container to serve the static website (named `$web`).

Is there a way to setup the account to provide two Static Website containers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now, it can only support one static website for one storage account. There is also [an issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/34608) about that.

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking about Static Web sites (Preview service) , the answer is NO

However if you are looking for static sites with Blob storage, Yes you can do it, You can deploy static SPAs in subfolders and have multiple at the same time on different subfolders.

Comment: thanks! I will consider that option too... but I would prefer not to use different subfolders

Comment: In case of HTML5 routing You will have an issue as You need to configure 404 page to be the same as index. Do You know if it is possible to configure different error pages per subfolder?